# android query on polling server

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm creating an app in android that would basically connect to the server and receive data which would be further processed for certain further tasks of my app. Currently I've just developed a sample app that is using Async task and connecting to the server and display the contents. Now, as I've learned that Async can be run only once, it doesnt fullfil my purpose because I want the changes in data on the server to be reflected in the app as well. I've found out that I must use IntentService, but the problem is battery drain and so i need a better solution that will help me. Could I use gcm and notify the app through server and solve the problem of battery drain? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use gcm service the gcm server sends a notification to ur device whenever new data is available to ur server. If u recieve the notification frm gcm then u can connect to ur own database and fetch the new data . The gcm services are more efficient and battery efficient too so u can use this . bt don't expect Much from this because gcm can send maximum 4kb data only.

Comment: Thank you, I dont know much about GCM. I read about it it creates the RegID at android side and at server side we send notifications to android using RegID of device.

Comment: Problem here is my application has this functioning where the data to be sent from server to device depends on the connectivity of the device. for example: say my android device is showing status of 'x' device. Now my nodejs has status information on server which is to be sent to the android if status changed.

Comment: Now there is possibility that today android1 was responsible for showing status of 'x' device. But tomorrow android1 will be replaced by android2 and still my server must sent data to android2, but as per GCM it will send to android1. So is there any mechanism that when i am registering my android device i can register it on random basis? as in as per the status of device i need to show ?

Answer (score 0):

then u have to use services. U can make make services battery efficient by calling them periodically or calling them when events happen. For example call your service in every 10 to 15 minutes. Because if u call ur service within 5 minutes interval then it drains 10% battery. u can achieve this by alarm manager class.

Or u can also call ur services on broadcast events like when user connects with internet then it sends a broadcast and u can regiser ur app for this broadcast and can check ur server for new data. Using broadcasts is more effective approach then calling services periodically.